# How to delete lines containing anything else than numbers and spaces

Tags: shell-script

I need to write a script that compiles some pascal programme, launches it and than deletes all lines of the output containing anything else than numbers and spaces. After that, I should print the first five lines.

It's a homework so we're allowed to use just this basic commands.

I know how to compile and launch the program. I also know how to print the first five lines in the end. But I'm stuck at deleting the lines.

Comment: Welcome to SE U&L, please take a look at the help center's guide on [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `[0-9 ]` matches one digit or a space.

The regular expression `[^0-9 ]` matches one character that is *not* a digit nor a space.

The `grep` command can be used to extract lines from a file or from the output of a program (via a pipe) that matches a particular regular expression.  The `grep` command has a `-v` flag that inverts the sense of the match so that only lines *not* matching the given regular expression are let through.

So, with those tools, you should be able to say something like

```
./myprogram | grep ...
```

You will need to fill in the dots yourself (as this is homework).

Comment: Kusalananda, you said `The regular expression [^0-9 ] matches one character that is not a digit nor a space.` Shouldn't it match all leading single digit and/or space?

Comment: @user9303970 The `^` character, in the beginning of a regular expression, anchors the expression to the start of the line. A bracket expression, `[...]`, matches one character from within that expression. When a `^` character is first in a `[...]`, it inverts the the sense of matching so that a character _not_ within the brackets is matched. It's `^` in both places, but its meaning is different.

Comment: @user9303970 So you could, for example, have `^[^=]`, which would mean "any line starting with something that isn't a `=`".

Comment: Oh, I confused an external `^` (before `[]`) with the internal one. Sorry. Very new to regex, aspiring to be more sensitive for that now.